# Two different syntax in grok

Tags: parsing, logstash, logstash-grok

A normal event could be like this:

```
 2015-11-20 18:50:33,739 [TRE01_0101] [76] [10.117.10.220]
```

but sometimes I have a log with "default" IP:

```
 2015-11-04 23:14:27,469 [TRE01_0101] [40] [default]
```

If I have defined in grok a [SYNTAX:SEMANTIC] pattern as follows:

```
grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:time} \[%{DATA:instance}\] \[%{NUMBER:numeric}\] \[%{IP:client}\]}"}

}
```

How can I parse a log that contains dafault as IP?

Now I'm getting a `_grokparsefailure` because "default" is not an "IP SYNTAX".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also note that brackets are used in regular expressions to show ranges, so you'll need to escape them.

Answer (score 1):

You can group things together and then make them conditional:

```
(%{IP:client}|default)
```

Comment: Thanks! Finally I tried next:

(\[%{IP:client}\]|\[%{DATA:client}\]) escaping brackets

Comment: If you want to keep everything as 'client', you might use a different pattern, like "\[(?<client>[^\]]*)\]".  This says "a bracket, capturing everything that's not a bracket, followed by another bracket".  Though in hind-sight, it might not be more clear :)